# How to change style of already loaded points from geojson file?

Tags: openlayers-3

I created a script which loads in features from a geojson file as so:

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [5.53204822887795, 51.609252234043296, 0.0]
    }
}, etc...
```

I then use a style function to create circles with different colors and radius sizes on those points:

```
var styleFunction = function(feature) {
var style = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: calculateRadius(feature),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)'
        }),
    stroke: null
    })
});

return style;
};
```

I would like to change the styling of those features, but for the life of me I have no way of accessing the style. I can access the coordinates (I guess because they're points), but getting the radius or color seems impossible.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your style function, try changing `return style;` to `return [style];`.

See my post here [Style Function example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287613/displaying-features-based-on-zoom-level/44308880#44308880)

Since each feature goes through the style function, you can also add properties to your geojson that can be read in your style function.  This is great if you want to do other things like make a square or enlarge a map feature based on a property of the feature.